# What is WSE2QuickStartServer and can we use other certificate instead of this one?

Tags: wcf, x509certificate, wse, wse3.0, wse2.0

In WSE, everywhere the `WSE2QuickStartServer` certificate is used to encrypt and sign the messages.

What is special about this certificate and can we use any other certificate? If yes, what requirements should be satisfied by the certificate?

Note: I know that WSE is a legacy technology but customers use it at the moment; so we have to support it anyway !

Comment: Actually, ASMX is a legacy technology. WSE is an _obsolete_ one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing special, you can use any other certificate. if you use it for signature you need to have a private key. basically any certificate that is good for ssl can work here also.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I tried to use my SSL certificate for message encryption (by replacing WSE2QuickStartServer) as well but it does not work.

Comment: I suggest you double click on the 2 certificates and compare their properties (details tab)

Comment: I have already compared the properties and for both the certificates, "Enable all purposes for this certificate" option is selected.

Comment: I get  `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  System.ArgumentException: OFSTS0003: X509TokenProvider is unable to provide an X.509 token. There are no certificates in the certificate store that match the find value of 'CN=MyserverCert'. `. I am using SSL server certificate as server signing and encryption.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your time. I was not using the correct `SubjectDistinguishedName`. I copied it from the actual certificate and used it in the code to find the certificate. And it worked :)